# I'm trying to hide/show a spinner when a file is equal to null but code is not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to show a spinner when a file is equal to null and then hide it when the file is not equal to null. I don't know why it is not working. Here's my code.

```
const submit2 = () => {
  try {
    while (!imageUrls) {
      setShow(true);

      if (imageUrls) {
        submit();
        setShow(false);
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: You can try looking at this new suspense feature introduced in React v18.0: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-suspense-features

Answer (score 0):

Try using `useEffect()` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (imageUrls) {
   submit();
   setShow(false);
  } else {
   setShow(true)
 }
}, [imageUrls])
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need to run a function that does that after pressing a button.